# Create seperate data frames and plots with a for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate pivot table creation so I can make multiple pivot tables at once. I would also like to graph these with a `sns.heatmap()` plot.

The code I have so far technically works but I'm forced to use a `print` command so the data doesn't come out in a data frame and the graph the is produced is extremely unreadable.

```
for i in list(df): 
y = pd.pivot_table(df, index = df[i], values=vector)
print(y)
```

This doesn't give the desired result of an individual data frame for each loop of the loop.

If I graph this with the code:

```
for i in list(df): 
y = pd.pivot_table(df, index = df[i], values=vector)
sns.heatmap(y, annot=True)
```

I get all the tables mushed into one long one with a n different heat map legends.

I've tried using dictionaries to get around this but I don't think this is the best approach (but what do I know?)

```
d={}
for i in list(df): 
    d[i] = pd.pivot_table(df, index = df[i], values=vector)
```

Any one have any tips?

Comment: check the indentation of the code here. It doesn't match.

Comment: what is `vector`

Comment: @MaartenFabré vector is a vector of column names that represent KPIs to be analysed in pivot table format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over a DataFrame, `for i in list(df)` is not the way to go.

As you yourself suggested, keeping the results in a dict is the easiest way. And split the generation with the plotting

```
d = {col_name: pd.pivot_table(df, index=col, values=vecor) for col_name, col in df.iteritems()}
```

Then plotting  can loop over the results, and do the plotting

```
for column_name, pivot_results in d:
    # plotting
```